# print type(x) SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

So I started learning python 3 and I wanted to run a very simple code on ubuntu:

```
print type("Hello World")
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I tried to compile that with command python3 hello.py in terminal it gave me the error above, but when used python hello.py (I think it means to use python 2 instead of 3) then it's all fine. Same when using python 3 and 2 shells in the terminal.

It seems like I'm missing something really stupid because I did some research and found no one with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

In Python3, `print` [was changed](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) from a statement to a function (with brackets):

i.e.

```
# In Python 2.x
print type("Hello World")
# In Python 3.x
print(type("Hello World"))
```

Comment: In 3.x `print` is not a statement.

Comment: @planetp true :)

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.x [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a function, while in 2.x it was a statement. The correct syntax in Python 3 would be:

```
print(type("Hello World"))
```

Comment: I just knew it was something dumb. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

[This is because from Python 3, `print` is a **function**, not a statement anymore.](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html#the-print-function) Therefore, Python 3 only accepts:

```py
print(type("Hello World"))
```